# Django / DRF HTTP_AUTHORIZATION vs AUTHORIZATION in tests

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using session authentication with Django and DRF

In my tests I need to set the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header, i.e. using APITestFactory

```
url = reverse("login")
token = base64.b64encode(b"user:password").decode()
auth_header_str = f"Basic {token}"
self.client.post(url, **{"HTTP_AUTHORIZATION": auth_header_str})
```

Where as, when using requests it needs AUTHORIZATION, i.e.

```py
token = base64.b64encode(b"user:password").decode()
auth_header_str = f"Basic {token}"
sesh = requests.Session()
r = sesh.post(
    "http://localhost:8000/auth/login",
    headers={"AUTHORIZATION": auth_header_str},
)
```

Neither works in both case and they both don't work in each others cases, why is this?

Comment: Can you try as `self.client.get(url, format="json", **{"HTTP_AUTHORIZATION":auth_header_str} )`

Comment: @DeepakTripathi I only have POST allowed for the login route at the moment, but either way I don't think it would change the root issue

Comment: You should only use tools designed for tests in django - `requests.Session` is not one of them.